# I'm trying to run my first spring application on eclipse IDE. Even though I've added the correct spring jars also, I'm getting this error

Tags: java, spring, noclassdeffounderror

When I ran this program on eclipse IDE, I'm getting this error.

Error: Unable to initialize main class springApplication.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

here's my HelloWorld.java class, Main.java class and beans.xml file.

*HelloWorld.java*

```
package springApplication;

public class HelloWorld {
       private String message;

       public void setMessage(String message){
          this.message  = message;
       }
       public void getMessage(){
          System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
       }
    }
```

*Main.java*

```
package springApplication;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       
//     System.out.println("Helloooo");
       
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.getMessage();
   }
}
```

*beans.xml*

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "com.springApplication.HelloWorld">
      <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Why not to use spring boot and initializr? https://start.spring.io/

Comment: make sure that the spring-context or something releative jar is exist in your ecplise ide env?

Comment: Can you show your build path? How are you running the program?